# Define function to be used by JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I have the following markup ([Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jRU5FuNFKvdOjZL46tuv?p=preview)):

```
<div class="slides">      
  <div class="slide" id="slide-01">
    <img src=""
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="slide-02">
    Slide 02 Content
  </div>
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#slide-01"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#slide-02"></a></li>
  </ul>      
</div>
```

I am creating a simple slider plugin:

```
$("div.slides").slider();
```

That would work as follows:

1. Add "active" class to first slide and first anchor in navigation;
2. After 8 seconds change active class to next slide and next anchor;
   So in this case I want to show the next slide and hide the previous one.
3. If an anchor is clicked in the navigation shows the slide which id is the same as the value in href of the anchor minus the #.

Basically that is it ... So I tried the following:

```
$(function () {

  $("div.slides").slider();

});

(function ($) {

  $.fn.slider = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
      delay: 800,
      speed: 200
    };

    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    $(this).each(function () {

      var $this = $(this);

      var $items = $this.children("div.slide");

      var $pages = $this.children("ul.pager li a");

      $items.first().addClass("active");

      $pages.first().addClass("active");

      var timer;

      start();

      $pages.on("click", function (e) {        

        e.preventDefault();

        console.log("here");

        show(this.attr("href").replace("#", ""));          

      });      

      var start = function start() {
        timer = setTimeout(next, 8000);
      };

      var stop = function stop() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };      

      var next = function next() {
        var item = $items.find(".active").next();        
        if (!item.length)
          item = $items.find(".active").first();
        show(item.attr("id"));  
      };

      var show = function show(id) {

        if ("#" + id == $this.children("ul.pager li a.active").attr("href")) 
          return;

        clearTimeout(timer);

        $items.removeClass("active").hide();

        $items.find("#id").first().addClass("active").fadeIn("slow");

        $pages.removeClass("active");

        $pages.find("a[href*=" + id + "]").first().addClass("active");

        start();

      }; // show

    });

    return this;

  };

})(jQuery);
```

I am having a few problems to make this work. One is that I get the error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: start is not a function $.fn.slider
```

This happens to all my functions ...

Comment: Have try to place Start definition function before calling ?

Comment: You should be using `var start = function () {...}` or `function start() {...}`, not a combination thereof.

Comment: @Terry `var start = function () {...}`  would have the same result, because `start` will still `undefined` at the time when `start()` is called some lines above. `function start() {...}` would work because of hoisting.

Comment: @t.niese I would suppose that OP knows about the quirks behind variable hoisting... but yes, that is something he should watch out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the:

```
  start();

  // ...      

  var start = function start() {
    timer = setTimeout(next, 8000);
  };
```

You `start()` tries to access the variable `var start` which is `undefined` at this point (the variable `start` hides the named function `start`). Either move `start` below that or get rid of the `var start =` in front of the function. Because then the named function `start` would be accessible because it is hoisted to the beginning of the scope.

```
  start();

  // ...      

  function start() {
    timer = setTimeout(next, 8000);
  };
```

You need to do that with all of your function where you use `var name = function name()`.

Comment: You suggestion makes it work ... Is there a standard way to do this? I mean to include function in a JQuery plugin? I am not sure if I am creating the plugin correctly because even when solving that problem I keep having problems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your JS line 32, start() function is called before it is defined. Remove it and call it below the function definition.

Comment: The problem is not the time when the function is defined, but that the `var start` hides the named function `start`, and that the `var start` is assigned after the call `start()`